# PHP regex to match expressions not containg a pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following text:

"This is a test text. Test, comma instead of space."

I iterate through each word and want to replace each word to a distinct link. Let's say

```
<a href="wordToReplace">wordToReplace</a>
```

My problem is that consecutive matches of the word "test" (to use the above example) replace the href and anchor text so I'm left with links inside links which is not good at all.

(to give a base idea of my problem this is what I'm left with. It has some additional markup.)

```
This is a<a href="/index.php?r<a href="/index.php?r=texts/addWord"
class="wordLink info label" id="yt2">text</a>/addWord" class="wordLink
info label" id="yt1">test</a>text.<a href="/index.php?r=texts/addWord"
class="wordLink info label" id="yt3">Test</a><a
href="/index.php?r=texts/addWord" class="wordLink info label"
id="yt4">comma</a>instead of<a href="/index.php?r=texts/addWord"
class="wordLink info label" id="yt6">space</a>
```

I'm trying

```
preg_replace("/[^\">]".$word."[^\"<]/", $link, $text->text);
```

but I don't think I'm on the right track at all.

Thanks for the time

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to use `str_replace()`?

Comment: Match on the original, replace on a copy using positions, or perhaps use the starting offset on the replacement, though you would need to calculate that as you went along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your one line of code, I'm assuming that you have that line in a loop which iterates through all the `$words` you want to replace, which causes the problem.

What you need to do is put all those replacements into only one `preg_replace` call. For that, regexes provide alternatives. So say, your list of words consisted of `test`, `text` and `this`. Then you could do:

```
preg_replace('/(test|text|this)/', $link, $text->text);
```

And if you have all your words in an array `$words` then you can generate the regex simply with:

```
$wordList = implode('|', $words);
preg_replace('/('.$wordList.')/', $link, $text->text);
```

You might want to add an `i` at the very end of your regex, if your checks are supposed to be case-insenstive.

In case some of your words are parts of other words (e.g. you want to replace `text` and `texture`), you could check for word boundaries:

```
preg_replace('/\b('.$wordList.')\b/', $link, $text->text);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

**EDIT:** If your `$link` was pre-generated for every `$word` in your loop before, you can now replace that word with `$1`. If your `$link` was something like

```
$link = '<a href="'.$word.'">'.$word.'</a>';
```

you can now simply use

```
$link = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
```

Comment: Why not use the word boundary operator '\b'?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! Can I use the word matched from the word list in the replacement somehow? I need to generate a different link for each word matched...

Comment: @jribeiro yes, if you write `$1` within `$link` then it will be replaced by the first capture (which is the word)

Comment: @jribeiro I added it to the answer

Comment: great!! Thanks. I'll try that out now. brb